# LDAP - Extract CN value from DN

Tags: php, ldap

I want to extract the CN value from DNs returned by `$output[$i]` in the code below:

```
$result=ldap_search($conn, $ldap_dn, "cn=$myId",array("givenname","sn","memberof","primarygroupid")) or die("No search data found."); 

$info = ldap_get_entries($conn, $result);

$output = $info[0]['memberof'];
array_shift($output);

$arrlen = count($output);
       for ($i=0; $i<$arrlen; $i++)
          {
          print $output[$i] . "\n";
          }
```

Example output is

```
CN=FMDHS-PLM-WebTest-3,OU=Permission,OU=Groups,DC=uniwa,DC=uwa,DC=edu,DC=au
```

So in this example I want to just get FMDHS-PLM-WebTest-3

Any ideas how I can do this?  Do I need to parse the string with PHP or is there something I can use in LDAP to acheive this?

**EDIT**

I ended up using [ldap_explode_dn](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-explode-dn.php)

```
$arrlen = count($output);
       for ($i=0; $i<$arrlen; $i++)
          {  
        $parsr=ldap_explode_dn($output[$i], 0); 
        print str_replace('CN=', '', $parsr[0]) . "\n";
          }
```

Comment: Still at it huh? At least things seem to be moving in the right direction :)

Comment: Yeah, pluggin away...  It'll all come together in the end (with some help from SO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this sample test:

```
<?php
$sample = "CN=FMDHS-PLM-WebTest-3,OU=Permission,OU=Groups,DC=uniwa,DC=uwa,DC=edu,DC=au";
$test = explode(",",$sample);
echo $test[0];
?>
```

Comment: I should of thought of that...and remove CN= with str_replace  There is also ldap_explode_dn.

Comment: And what if there are commas in one of the values? A comma is still a valid value for a cn/ou. Simply exploding the DN string with a comma is not enough.

Comment: @ChadSikorra this sample code is based on the OP specs...cheers.